# Как правильно запустить JavaFX программу из репозитория?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, github, maven, jar

Есть значит один репозиторий - https://github.com/spheenik/clarity-analyzer - **не реклама**

**Мне нужно запустить программу, как она показана на скриншоте.** Я уже скачанный .jar файл в IDEA открывал, открывал мастер-папку через проекты в IDEA, через командную строку пытался открыть, но постоянно выдавало то **no main manifest attribute in jar**, то *забилдить не получалось...* (в IDEA при этом был импортирован protobuf, если я правильно это понимаю). Листал разные форумы - пишут указать Main-Class в MANIFEST, но я не знаю где mainclass у этой огромной (для меня) программы. **Да и Java я знаю как игрок в Майнкрафт, не более...** Разве что немного Python, и всё...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опишу процесс запуска из командной строки.

1. Необходимо установить JDK 8 в котором есть JavaFX. Подходящую версию можно скачать например с сайта [azul.com](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-8-lts&os=windows&package=jdk-fx). При загрузке обрати внимание чтобы была версия JDK FX.
2. Для сборки используется [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi).
3. Получить локальную копию репозитория с Github.
4. Перейти в корень папки с проектом, где лежит файл pom.xml.
5. С помощью команды `mvn package` собрать проект. В папке `target` появится файл `analyzer.one-jar.jar`. Его и можно будет запустить с помощью команды `java -jar target\analyzer.one-jar.jar`.

Comment: Сейчас попробую и отпишусь. Спасибо! :)

Comment: Помогло. Большое спасибо!)